# Python How To instantly detect TCP cable unplugged

Tags: python, tcp, disconnect

I have a real-time python program that needs to know instantly when the Ethernet cable becomes disconnected. I cannot wait for the usual TCP timeout. I'm operating on a 500 msec polling loop and need to respond to a cable-out situation in less than 1.5 seconds. Is there any way to query the status of the socket without doing an I/o operation like send or recv?

Comment: There is nothing like reliable real-time error detection on a network link. At best it will detect some of the possible faults. If you would go more in the detail why you have this requirement maybe we can offer a better solution.

Comment: Can you give us more information about what system you are running on?

Comment: It might be better to use UDP if you have such a requirement, but it can be difficult to traverse firewalls with UDP.   Trading platforms have a similar requirement; if the client disconnects from the exchange, it is generally desired to cancel the active orders of the client.  Every such system I have knowledge of does this by sending heartbeat messages (in a higher level protocol on top of TCP) periodically, and if you fail to receive a heartbeat after a suitable timeout, take corrective action (e.g. show the user they are disconnected at the client and pull the orders at the server).

Comment: I am running on a Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu and Python 3. I am trying to communicate to several devices through a Brainbox ED-008 which is connected via TCP with an Ethernet cable. It is important to detect when the Brainbox is disconnected ASAP because I have other devices that must be stopped if I've lost connectivity. I have no control over the brainbox to cause it to send heartbeats or not.

Comment: Is the RP connected directly to the BB with a single cable, or does it go through router/switch and the BB relies on network services like DHCP to get an IP address?

Comment: The brainbox and Raspberry are connected directly with a short (1 foot) ethernet cable. No DHCP, etc

Comment: @Alandoe Then perhaps ping (i.e. send an ICMP echo request) at a suitable frequency and take appropriate action if you do not receive a reply after a suitable timeout?  See, e.g., https://pypi.org/project/icmplib/.  This would detect cable failures and many other failures as well.  Will not detect application level failure on the BB, however.